# Prove that a group of order 85 has an element of order 5 (without Cauchy or Sylow)

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

First off: I'm not able to use Cauchy or Sylow as we've not covered these in the course yet.

So, I've managed to half complete this as follows:

Suppose $x \in G.$ Then, by Lagrange's Theorem,
$|x|$ divides $85 \implies |x|$ is one of $1,5,17,85$

Without loss of generality we can assume $|x| \neq 1 \iff x = e$ as $|G| \geq 2$.

Suppose $|x| = 5$, then we are done.

Suppose $|x|=85$, which implies $|x^{17}| = 5$ as $(x^{17})^5 = x^{85} = e$. Then we are done.

But, I'm really struggling to work with 17. I'm thinking I'll have to do a proof by contradiction, and I'm assuming the fact the $17$ is prime is probably relevant, but I have scoured my lecture notes and I cannot find anything that we've been presented relating to the order of an element being prime. Any help would be massively appreciated.

Comment: So you have reached the point where all the elements would have order $17$ or $1$. Each element of order $17$ lies in a subgroup of order $17$ and by Lagrange theese don't overlap, OK? So now $G$ will have $1+16n$ elements ... oh dear.

Comment: @ancientmathematician How does Lagrange's theorem imply that the subgroups would not overlap? (Edit because I understand the first part!)

Comment: (1) because each elt $x$ of order $17$ has more or less by definition $17$ distinct powers $x^r$ and these clearly form a subgroup of order $17$. (2) If $A$ and $B$ have order $17$ then by Lagrange $A\cap B$ has order $1$ or $17$, and if it is $17$ then $B=A\cap B=A$ etc.

Comment: @ancientmathematician Thank you! I think I do understand, however, what would be the relation to cosets here? As to use Lagrange in that way (in my understanding) I would need to specify that these order 17 subgroups are cosets of some subgroup in G? Or am I overthinking this

Comment: Compare with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1293295/group-of-order-10-has-an-element-of-order-5-without-using-cauchys-or-sylows-t), or [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/552333/show-any-group-of-order-275-has-an-element-of-order-5?rq=1),  and others.

Comment: Cosets are irrelevant: you have Lagrange's Thm and that's all you need.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose $x \in G.$ Then, by Lagrange's Theorem,
$|x|$ divides $85 \implies |x|$ is one of $1,5,17,85$

Without loss of generality we can assume $|x| \neq 1 \iff x = e$ as $|G| \geq 2$.

Suppose $|x| = 5$, then we are done.

Suppose $|x|=85$, which implies $|x^{17}| = 5$ as $(x^{17})^5 = x^{85} = e$. Then we are done.

There is only one element in $G$ with order $1$ - the identity element.

Suppose there is no element of order $5$ in $G$, then the remaining $84$ elements of $G$ must be of order 17. Thus, each element (other than the identity) generates a subgroup of order 17. For each distinct subgroup, there will be $16$ distinct elements, as the all necessarily contain the identity element.

Hence, if there are $n$ such distinct subgroups there will be $16n + 1$ elements in $G$, and

$85 = 16n + 1 \iff 84 = 16n$

However, $16 \nmid 84$ and thus we have a contradiction of Lagrange's Theorem.

Therefore, G must have an element of order 5.